# Computer powers on but not detected by monitor

Tags: memory, graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, computer-building

I’m new to PC building and I’ve just completed my first build I did with a friend. Upon finishing we went to boot it up and there is no beep sound, the lights turn on, and all fans spin,  but after a few seconds the graphics card fans stop spinning, and nothing displays on the monitor at any time. I’ve tried moving the ram from slots 1 and 3 to 2 and 4 as well as triple checked everything is plugged in properly and I’m not sure what’s causing the issue. Any help would be appreciated

specs are
CPU: Intel i5 10400F
Motherboard: As rock 460m pro 4
Ram: 2 8GB sticks of DDR4
Storage: MX500 1TB SSD
Graphics: GeForce RTX 2070s
Power: Corsair CX650M semi modular bronze

Comment: @Romen  turns out you are right, I tried switching ports before switching the ram and not after and all I needed to do was plug the hdmi into the video card thanks so much! You saved me a lot of time and frustration

Comment: Don't forget to check the checkmark on the answer to accept it to the upper left side of the [below] answer.

Answer (score 1):

Most Intel CPUs have integrated graphics, except the models that end in F do not. If your monitor is plugged in to the video ports on the motherboard they will be inactive and you will get no video.

Make sure that your monitor is plugged in to the RTX 2070.